# I want to know principle of call smart contract in web3.js

Tags: blockchain, web3js

Explain my current situation.

1. I deployed smart contract using Remix IDE on Ganache local environment.
2. I call smart contract function in web3.js on express.js server. like below
   await contract.methods['myMethod'](parameters).send({from: walletAddress, gas: '1000000'});

in this situation, I have first question.

**Q1. When calling Ganache's smart contract, it's call with only public wallet address, but how do I prevent the situation of indiscriminately call smart contract function with someone else's wallet address?**

And I wanted to experience this situation on Public Ethereum Testnet (Sepolia), so I deployed a simple experimental contract using Remix IDE, MetaMask Provider, and MetaMask Sepolia wallets.

my simple experimental contract address in Sepolia. (0x56926CB88108126d30AF0844FDBB12522A34D01a)
https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x56926cb88108126d30af0844fdbb12522a34d01a

When i create contract instance in Ganache, like below.

```
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://127.0.0.1:7545'));
const contractAddress = '...' const contractABI = [...]
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI, contractAddress);
```

in this progress, I have second question.

**Q2. What kind of Provider should I use to call smart contract on Sepolia?**

and My last question

**Q3. Is that possible to view my simple experimental contract original code on etherscan? How to do that?**

The best thing I found is the below. but that is not my original code.
https://sepolia.etherscan.io/bytecode-decompiler?a=0x56926CB88108126d30AF0844FDBB12522A34D01a

Thanks for reading. please tell me if anyone know this.

I wrote this in the details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Q1. When calling Ganache's smart contract, it's call with only public wallet address, but how do I prevent the situation of indiscriminately call smart contract function with someone else's wallet address?*

You can validate the value of `msg.sender`, a global variable that reflects the address of the caller.

For example

```
function foo() external {
    require(msg.sender == address(0x123), "Not authorized");
}
```

If this function is called by anyone else than the address `0x123`, it throws the error `Not authorized`.

This mechanism is also used in the widely known OpenZeppelin [Ownable](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/access-control#ownership-and-ownable) library, where the authorized address is known as the `owner`.

---

> *Q2. What kind of Provider should I use to call smart contract on Sepolia?*

There are quite a few 3rd party providers that enable you to interact with contracts on Sepolia. Most of them have a free tier that should be sufficient for your use case. Google "sepolia RPC provider".

---

> *Q3. Is that possible to view my simple experimental contract original code on etherscan? How to do that?*

You need to verify your source code on each blockchain explorer where you want the code to be displayed (in your case Etherscan).

What you see now, is the compiled (machine-readable) bytecode that was generated from the Solidity (human-readable) source code.

Here's a link to the Etherscan verification tutorial: https://docs.etherscan.io/tutorials/verifying-contracts-programmatically You can verify the code either using their UI or programmatically.

Comment: thanks for reply.

I have more question.

In your answer for Q1. I learned something new about Concept of Ownable. Thanks. But I don’t think that is not what I want. I want to see web3.js function that create signed transaction using user’s private key. I found similar function that personal_signTransaction API in web3.js, but this function require only passphrase not private key. There is no any function in web3.js API to create signed transaction using private key?

Comment: In your answer for Q3. I understood that it was difficult for that decompile to original code because code to be compiled into byte code when deploying. Right? Then if I want to call arbitrary smart contract on public blockchain how to do that? there is way to get ABI?

Comment: @PJH Q3: Exactly - the ABI essentialy serves as a key to encode the called function name and arguments into the binary that the contract understands... If the contract implements some standard (e.g. ERC20), then part of the ABI for the standardized functions is always the same (here's a generic [ERC20 ABI](https://gist.github.com/veox/8800debbf56e24718f9f483e1e40c35c) for example). But if it implements some custom functions, they are missing from the generic ABI and you need to retrieve the contract specific ABI (usually shared by the contract author) for these custom functions.

Comment: @PJH Q1: On backend apps, `web3.js` can sign the transaction directly using a private key that you provided into the web3js instance using the [wallet.add()](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.10.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#wallet-add) function... On frontend, `web3.js` is usually just an intermediary and doesn't sign the transactions directly. Instead it sends the transaction to MetaMask or another wallet to sign. You can connect to these wallets using the `wallet.ethereum` object: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.10.0/getting-started.html?highlight=window.ethereum#adding-web3-js

Comment: Why can the sign transaction process with private keys be only backend web3.js? Can't I call the "wallet.add()" function on the front end web3.js?

Comment: @PJH Technically, you can also pass the private key on the front end directly. But it's generally not recommended to publish sensitive data (e.g. private keys) in the front end code because it's readable by end users if they open the front end code in their browser.